# How to click on a nested checkbox using Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I want to check the first checkbox with id=user_accepts_terms. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="check-group">

<div class="checkbox">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[accepts_terms]">
</input>
<input id="user_accepts_terms" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[accepts_terms]">
</input>
<label class="" for="user_accepts_terms">
</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[subscribed]">
</input>
<input id="user_subscribed" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[subscribed]">
</input>
<label class="m-focus" for="user_subscribed">
</label>
</div>
```

I want to check the first checkbox with id=user_accepts_terms. Tried this among other things, but no luck:

```
find('.check-group').all('.checkbox')[0].find("#user_accepts_terms").set(true)
```

The `.find("#user_accepts_terms").set(true)` doesn't work, it says unable to find the css.

This piece works as follows:

```
2.1.0 :097 > find('.check-group').all('.checkbox')[0].text
 => "I accept the terms of use and privacy policy"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.all('.checkbox')[0]` portion is already finding the checkbox you want, and the `.find("#user_accepts_terms")` portion is trying to find another element below that, which doesn't exist. Either of the following should work, provided the syntax is correct (I'm unfamiliar with it)

```
find('.check-group').find("#user_accepts_terms").set(true)
find('.check-group').all('.checkbox')[0].set(true)
```